# How do I blend/fade images with background color on inkscape

Tags: inkscape, images, transparency, background

I normally use transparency tool on Corel Draw to blend two images together or an image with either colored or black background with fade in fade out effects. Recently I started using Linux, unfortunately no Corel Draw in Linux but Inkscape as one alternative. I know it can be done with GIMP but please how do I achieve the same effects with Inkscape?

This is a sample picture of what I want to achieve. I did this with Corel Draw.

[image: Sample]

Comment: Welcome on GDm ellooku! Have you tried to use a [gradient](https://inkscape.org/en/doc/basic/tutorial-basic.html) with alpha color? See also [here](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Attributes-Fill-Stroke.html), try and tell us something about your efforts.

Comment: Thank you so much @Paolo Gibellini. I learnt alot from your direction. Gradient with alpha color did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to come up with this result using alpha color and linear gradient.

[image: Sample]

@Paolo Gibellini, Thanks.

Comment: It's important to remark that the right-hand side of that colour gradient should be a transparent white (instead of e.g. defaulting to a transparent black if one is not careful, which will leave ugly stripes in the image.

Comment: If you overlay a rectangle with a gradient like this, select the gradient and image, and click Object->Mask->Set, the parts covered in white will be visible, and where the gradient fades to transparent (or black), the image will fade out to transparent.  Then you'll be able to put other things behind it.

Comment: Thank you both for your input. Its very helpful for my future projects.

Comment: Could you explain how you do this more specifically please? I can't repeat it, what are the exact steps?